# Rebind jquery plugin after refreshed via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, plugins, bind

I have a grid showing the 10 records. The next set of records are loaded via ajax request. Every record has a button called `Activate/Deactivate` to toggle the active status.

This `button` is bind with a jquery `alerts` plugin which initially works perfectly. However, when the next set of records are loaded with ajax request, the plugin doesn't work. I have to rebind the plugin with the buttons every time.

Here is my code:

```js
function actionStatus() 
{
    $('.js-status').alerts({
        customClass: 'gmail',
        heading: 'Switching activity status..?',
        message: 'Are you sure.?<br><br>`Proceed` to continue<br>`Cancel` to exit',
        buttons: {
            ok: {
                text: 'Proceed',
                class: 'buttons green',
                click: function ($this, e) {
                    $this.next('form').submit();
                }
            },
            cancel: {
                text: 'Cancel',
                class: 'buttons lightRed',
                focus: true
            }
        }
    });
}

actionStatus();
```

After ajax call:

```js
$.ajax({
    ...
    complete: function() {
        ...

        actionStatus();
    }
})
```

Is there a way where I don't have to bind the plugin again.

Comment: What is the plugin you are using?

Comment: Its a custom plugin for alert boxes, instead of showing the traditional alerts or confirms.

Comment: I just want to know what .alerts(...) does. And what is the element(s) of `.js-status`?

Comment: The `.js-status` is an `anchor` tag, which is used to activate or deactivate the selected record. And `.alerts()` does this https://prnt.sc/sy392n, its a custom plugin which I developed. However, the point is that whatever plugin is used, it has to be binded again and again, after every ajax request to attach the plugin with the newer elements, such as `.js-status` which is loading with the newer records.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Since you said you used a custom plugin and I don't know how you bind your events, I will give a general answer as to how you could do it.*

You can bind to `document` instead of the element receiving the event.

For example, instead of:

```
$('.mybutton').on('click', callback);
```

which only attachs to elements that exist, you can do:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mybutton', callback);
```

which attachs to the document itself, and listens to events coming from future DOM elements as well.

Comment: I have already tried this method, but it doesn't work on plugins.

Comment: Since you said you developed the plugin, which means you can change out the event handlers are attached. With this way, you don't have to reattach to your dynamically created elements. Maybe use this technique in your plugin

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you :)